# SQL run Variable +1 until Variable reaches 52?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a sproc that is basically:

```
declare @StartDate date
declare @EndDate date
declare @WeekNumber int

set @StartDate = '01/06/2014'
set @EndDate = '07/06/2015'
set @WeekNumber = 01

select @WeekNumber [WeekNumber]
,dateadd(ww,(@WeekNumber-1),@startDate) [WeekStartDate]
,dateadd(dd,6,dateadd(ww,(@WeekNumber-1),@startDate)) [WeekEndDate]
,* 
From (Select t1.LeadSource
                    ,count(t1.prospectid) [Leads]
                    ,sum(t1.Found) [Apps]
        from Table T1 
        where t1.CreateDate between dateadd(ww,(@WeekNumber-1),@startDate)
            and cast(convert(varchar(10),dateadd(dd,6,dateadd(ww,(@WeekNumber-1),@startDate)),101) as datetime)) f
GROUP BY f.LeadSource
```

This is would be how it looks when it is returned

```
WeekNumber  WeekStartDate   WeekEndDate Leads  Apps 
1           2014-01-06      2014-01-12  30     3
```

I need to run this for the last 2 years, with it cycling through each week and returning it by Week number, if that makes sense.

Is there a way to loop through the @WeekNumber Variable and have it stop when it hits 52 weeks or even 104?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The usual method for this type of thing is to cross join with an auxiliary numbers table or tally table.

Comment: Saw this to late... I just added an answer with a suggestion how to create a numbers table "on the fly"...

Answer (score 2):

If you are thinking in terms of looping, you are going down the wrong path. You need to think in terms of set-based logic. What you need to do is get rid of the @weeknumber variable altogether, and just group your data differently. You want to group by weeks, so you need to calculate the week number. You can do this by using DATEDIFF() and DATEPART(dw,...):

```
declare @StartDate date
declare @EndDate date
declare @WeekNumber int

set @StartDate = '01/06/2014'
set @EndDate = '07/06/2015'
--set @WeekNumber = 01

select datediff(ww,@startdate,[WeekStartDate])+1 [WeekNumber]
,[WeekStartDate]
,dateadd(dd,6,[WeekStartDate]) [WeekEndDate]
,* 
From (Select t1.LeadSource
                    ,count(t1.prospectid) [Leads]
                    ,sum(t1.Found) [Apps]
                    ,dateadd(dd,2-datepart(dw,t1.CreateDate),t1.CreateDate) WeekStartDate
        from Table T1 
        where t1.CreateDate between @startDate
            and @enddate
GROUP BY f.LeadSource ) f
```

Comment: I see what you are saying here, but I am not 100% on it. specifically the syntax around [WeekStartDate]. 

I am trying to work with it now though, Thank you for your time

Comment: I am doing 2 things. First I am getting the datepart(dw,t1.createdate). That gives me the weekday (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 or 7). I take that as a difference from 2. So if it is Wednesday (day 4), then 2-4 = -2. Then I use dateadd, to change the date by that much, always bringing us back to Monday. If you use 1- instead of 2- you'll get Sunday.

Comment: try this in SQL Server: select getdate() Today, datepart(dw,getdate()) weekdayOfToday, dateadd(dd,2-datepart(dw,getdate()),getdate()) ThisMonday

Comment: I missed that section changed as well, I only noticed the starting Select changed, I didn't see where you had changed the from Select other than the Where clause. I apparently need more coffee

Comment: 2-datepart(dw is a favorite of mine. any time I want to group in weeks, I pull that old friend out of the toolbox.

Comment: So I sorted it out, but it didn't actually work. I would link the result set, but I rolled back the changes and am just going to Copy Paste, and then Change the WeekNumber Variable to add +1 to each iteration. It isn't elegant, but it will work and I need to get this sent over to Marketing ASAP

Answer (score 0):

One funny way could be something like this:

I use such a function in my db to generate a running set of numbers whenever I need this...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RunningNumber(@Counter AS INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT TOP (@Counter) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY o.object_id) AS RunningNummber
FROM sys.objects AS o; --take any large table here...
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.RunningNumber(100)
```

Make sure to use a @Counter which is not higher then the row count of the table you use. You can JOIN this to a given SELECT and then use Modulo 7 (`% 7`) for your grouping...