# Calculating a running count of Weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am looking to calculate a running count of the weeks that have occurred since a starting point.  The biggest problem here is that the calendar I am working on is not a traditional Gregorian calendar.

The easiest dimension to reference would be something like 'TWEEK' which actually tells you the week of the year that the record falls into.

Example data:

```
CREATE TABLE #foobar
(   DateKey INT
    ,TWEEK INT
    ,CumWEEK INT
);

INSERT INTO #foobar (DateKey, TWEEK, CumWEEK)
VALUES(20150630, 1,1),
    (20150701,1,1),
    (20150702,1,1),
    (20150703,1,1),
    (20150704,1,1),
    (20150705,1,1),
    (20150706,1,1),
    (20150707,2,2),
    (20150708,2,2),
    (20150709,2,2),
    (20150710,2,2),
    (20150711,2,2),
    (20150712,2,2),
    (20150713,2,2),
    (20150714,1,3),
    (20150715,1,3),
    (20150716,1,3),
    (20150717,1,3),
    (20150718,1,3),
    (20150719,1,3),
    (20150720,1,3),
    (20150721,2,4),
    (20150722,2,4),
    (20150723,2,4),
    (20150724,2,4),
    (20150725,2,4),
    (20150726,2,4),
    (20150727,2,4)
```

For sake of ease, I did not go all the way to 52, but you get the point. I am trying to recreate the 'CumWEEK' column. I have a column already that tells me the correct week of the year according to the weird calendar convention ('TWEEK').

I know this will involve some kind of OVER() windowing, but I cannot seem to figure It out.

Comment: I would start with a table of just dates, create a helper table that starts at 0 and ends at 365. Combine these with a cross join, and add the cross of the numbers and start date together to produce the full year. Then from there calculate out every 7th day and take the sum of the total rows returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The windowing function `LAG()` along with a summation of `ORDER BY ROWS BETWEEN` "Changes" should get you close enough to work with. The caveat to this is that the `ORDER BY ROWS BETWEEN` can only take an integer literal.

**Year Rollover** : I guess you could create another ranking level based on mod 52 to start the count fresh. So 53 would become year 2, week 1, not 53.

```
SELECT
    *   ,
    SUM(ChangedRow) OVER (ORDER BY DateKey ROWS BETWEEN 99999 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)    
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        DateKey,
        TWEEK,  
        ChangedRow=CASE WHEN LAG(TWEEK) OVER (ORDER BY DateKey) <> TWEEK THEN 1 ELSE 0 END          

    FROM 
        @foobar F2
)AS DETAIL
```

Answer (score 2):

Some minutes ago I answered a different question, in a way this is a similar question to
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31303395/5089204

The idea is roughly to create a table of a running number and find the weeks with modulo 7. This you could use as grouping in an OVER clause...

EDIT: Example

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RunningNumber(@Counter AS INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT TOP (@Counter) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY o.object_id) AS RunningNumber
FROM sys.objects AS o; --take any large table here...
GO

SELECT 'test',CAST(numbers.RunningNumber/7 AS INT)
FROM dbo.RunningNumber(100) AS numbers
```

Dividing by 7 "as INT" offers a quite nice grouping criteria.

Hope this helps...

Comment: This way does not work for my situation because I may actually have 2 Week 52s (meaning 14 days in 1 week). I don't know why, that's just how it is

Comment: It does not matter which calendar you are using. Dealing with dates is always an ugly thing... Especially the "week 52" is defined in many ways... I'll edit my answer to give an exampel...

Comment: Doesn't it matter though? If I have 14 days that technically are all within 'Week 52', then your modulo way will break those 14 days into 2 weeks right? Thanks

Comment: Off course it matters... I just wanted to state, that dealing with dates and weeks are always a mess, no matter what calendar you use :-) How many years do you cover? What about the following: Create a SELECT which comes close to the thing you need. copy the data to EXCEL, change some  values manually and place them in an aux table finally? If you don't cover thousands of years this is to be done in 15 minutes... (please vote up if helpfull)